# Problem with request and events fired in ASP.net Global.asax on a postback from a payment gateway on Chrome 80+

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, postback

I have ASP.net web forms application that integrates with a certain payment gateway. After the payment gateway does its magic it posts back the response back to my site on to dedicated web page. The page accepts postback data and stores it in the database.

A very simple process that was working flawlessly up until Google released its Chrome v80 browser. Then in some instances, not always, only on these new versions of Chrome, some postback requests from the payment gateway started failing. All other browsers still work fine, even older versions of Chrome.

I suspected that the problem is with cookies and that new SameSite rule Google imposed in this new version of Chrome. I read about that issue and what to do to make my app support those Google changes, but it seems that the issue is not relevant to my problem because most of the time postbacks work just fine. I spent some time fiddling with it anyway, I even upgraded my web to .net Framework 4.8, but it didn't help.

By analyzing error logs I noticed that there is no content in the postback from the payment gateway sent back to my site. During the forensics, I implemented all request related event handlers in global.asax on my web site to track what is going on with requests. And what I found got me even more confused.

Normally, for all valid postback requests, the first event triggered is always BeginRequest and the others follow, ending with these three events:

1. EndRequest
2. PreSendRequestHeaders
3. PreSendRequestContent

But, in the failed postbacks, BeginRequest is not the first event fired. It is EndRequest, followed by the other two events mentioned above. Those three events have access to the correct postback content.
After those three events, BeginRequest is fired and all events that are supposed to go after it. But from BeginRequest on, there is no request content. It seems like the request's content is being reset or disposed of after those first three events, and a new HTTPRequest (or even HTTPContext) is initialized but without content.

I really do not understand what is going on and in week-long research, I could not find anything related to my problem. I tried all sorts of tricks to try to transfer the postback content form the first three events into the next BeginRequest, but with no success.

This is what I discovered so far:

- a valid postback starts with BeginRequest event
- an invalid postback starts with EndRequest event
- for valid postbacks, the session cookie and all other cookies are available
- for the failed postbacks, the session cookie and most of the other cookies are not available in the first three events (it smells like SameSite issue?) but they are available later in the rest of the events
- in the failed postback, after the first three events, HTTPContext Items collection and local variables within global.asax are being reset

There are two facts that confuse me:

1. Problem is obviously related to something Google did to Chrome in the latest version, but why is it so inconsistently occurring? It would be obvious that there is something wrong with my app if it would fail always.
2. What the heck is going on with ASP.net request processing events in global.asax? How is it possible that the first event is EndRequest? I have never seen this behavior before.

Any piece of advice, hint or push in the right direction is welcome. Maybe I don't see something that is very obvious, so please, help me see it. If there is anything unclear in my description, do tell so that I try to clarify it.

**EDITED:**
After more investigation (read googling) and testing I was able to resolve the second issue, the EndRequest event triggering first. EndRequest is triggered first if an unhandled exception occurs before the BeginRequest event is fired. In my case, it was an exception within one of the HTTP Modules. After the exception reason was fixed there were no more issues with EndRequest event.

But now I'm tackling missing cookies in the failed requests, what probably seems to be the result of invalid cookie definition (SameSite=None, Secure not being applied correctly). In the production environment, cookies are being rejected when submit comes from the payment gateway. It works OK on the dev site, but not in the production.

Comment: Does your own code set any cookies anywhere? Please post a screenshot of Chrome's Cookies panel before and after the redirection.

Comment: Can you be more precise when you use the term "postback"? A POST request itself is not a "postback", whereas only a WebForms' POST request  with its ViewState, EventValidation, using data pulled from a Web Form's GET HTML response is truly a "Postback" - so I'm unsure if you're refering to WebForms Postbacks or generic POST requests being sent to your application.

Comment: @Dai My app does set some cookies but none during the postback from Payment Gateway

Comment: **All** requests will result in the `Global::Application_BeginRequest` method being invoked - I suspect there's a bug somewhere in your application which interferes with your telemetry (don't forget that `Global` and `HttpApplication` object instances are not singletons (this is a common misconception). In reality, ASP.NET will create N-many instances of `Global`/`HttpApplication` for each request thread in its thread-pool but will only raise events on certain object instances.

Comment: @Dai By postback I mean POST request that Payment Gateway makes back to my App

Comment: Does this only happen in production or can you reproduce it locally on your local development machine (and/or your staging or dev server?) Can you re-play the payment gateway's requests (e.g. using `cURL`,`wget` or a `fetch` request from within a browser?

Comment: @Dai Probably there is some kind of a bug, but the problem is that I can't reproduce it. And so far it occurred only in production.

Comment: Also, what webserver (IIS) settings are in-effect? Does your IIS Website instance have any custom configuration?